# Cutted fonts (font squirrel) in Windows

Tags: font-face

I'm using font squirrel. Everything is fine on MacOSX or ipad. But I've got problem on my windows machine.

Font is just cutted.

It's original font(DinCond) on the bottom of the picture.
http://postimage.org/image/b3apbrwtd/

Answer (score 1):

According to this, the thinner and condensed fonts usually have this issue.
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2009/11/what-to-expect-from-our-font-face-generator

This might spark some attempts:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/forum/discussion/74/webkit-font-rendering-on-windows-xp/p1
might want to play around with CSS alias settings

You can always try Cufon and spend a little on TypeKit